# Messages for velocity and acceleration

Tags: ros, message, geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

is there a message which contains linear and rotational velocities and accelerations on the three axis?

I toke a look in the geometry and navigation messages but I didn't find what I need.

I'm looking for something similar to `geometry_msgs::Twist` + accelerations.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28038/messages-for-velocity-and-acceleration/) by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2012-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

You might take a look at the `sensor_msgs::Imu` [here](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Imu.html).
It comes with `angular_velocity` and `linear_acceleration` fields.
It doesn't have linear velocities though.

If you are using an IMU, that's what you are looking for.
Otherwise, to my best knowledge, you'll have to make your own msg (see [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Messages) how to do so).

Enrique

---

Originally posted by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) with karma: 834 on 2012-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on 2012-02-20**:
@Enrique Thanks, actually I have to send the velocities and accelerations of my mobile base. It isn't an IMU. I know how to make new messages, however I was looking for an existing solution in order to reuse as much as I can.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-02-21**:
I would recommend publishing both TwistStamped and Imu topics simultaneously, with identical time stamps.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `geometry_msgs/Twist` message provides with linear and angular velocities, but that's the closest one that I know of by default. The easiest I can think of is something like:

```
geometry_msgs/Twist velocities
geometry_msgs/Vector3 accelerations
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3